# Get public posts by keywords from Facebook using API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

As part of the wildlife protection work, a tool is being developed to search for illegal hunting sales and advertisements on Facebook by keyword. Is there a way to get the posts related to the sale of illegal class organs, along with who made them and when? Can Graph API help with this?

Comment: No, there is no search for that. Plus, "public" does not mean that you automatically get API access to this content.

Comment: thanks. What if I use Web Scraping? What do you think?

Comment: scraping is not allowed on facebook.